# Calls inside a module: resolved by the compiler or linker?

Tags: c, compilation, linker

If a function f() is called and implemented in the same c file (module) - who resolves this call? The compiler or the linker?

Comment: Simply it is linker! Linker is a part of the compiler!

Comment: @Sathish, the linker is typically part of the compiler *suite*, but it's distinct from the actual compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's technically implementation-dependent, but typically references within the same file will be resolved by the compiler.  There's no point deferring it until link time since the compiler knows which function is being called, and the compiler may be able to generate the code for the function call more efficiently if it doesn't have to leave a place for the linker to fill in an address.  (For example, it may be able to use a relative jump instruction with a 16-bit offset for a call to a nearby function, instead of an absolute jump with a 32-bit or 64-bit address embedded in the code.)

This may change if the called function is declared as a [weak symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol):  in that case, although the function is defined in the current translation unit, that definition may be overridden by one from another module at link time, so the compiler has to treat it as a call to a function in another module.

Comment: Tnx! So it is not defined in the standard whether it is the linker or the compiler?

Comment: I don't have a copy of the C standard to check, but the C++ standard just specifies the rules for whether a function is visible in other translation units based on its "linkage" (external or internal).  The specifics of how to to actually resolve cross-module references (i.e. linking) is left to the implementation.  I expect the same is true in C.

Comment: @eva: The standard doesn't know compiler/linker/etc., the whole system (hardware, preprocessor, compiler, linker, libc, execution environment) is called "the implementation" (could be an interpreter for example, although the standard primarily addresses the traditional setup).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the symbol's linkage. If `f` is an internal function such as those declared/defined with **static**, then `f` is resolved in the compiling (by the compiler). If the `f` is a [weak symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol), then it is resolved in the dynamically linking (by the dynamic loader). If `f` is a strong symbol, then it is resolved in the compiling (by the compiler).

Especially, when the program is compiled with optimization, `f` may be directly inlined into the caller's body which is done by the compiler.